# Проверка числа, целое или нет

Tags: java

Возможно ли через оператор "if" определить целое ли число и выполнить соответствующее действие, если оно целое?

Comment: Вас интересует именно через IF или можно и другим способом?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под числом? Строка, содержащая число? Или какой-то числовой тип?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите вывести простые числа в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743027/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (x % 1 == 0) {
    //целое
}
```

Comment: А разве при x=3.5 этот оператор не выдаст истину? Или в джаве % не строго целочисленная операция?!

Comment: Все будет хорошо :) 3.5%1=0.5

Comment: Так проверить нельзя, например System.out.println(94868978.999999999%1) -> 0.0

Comment: А как бы вы тогда сделали?

Comment: @Stas168, подозреваю, что оно и есть целое.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать `IntStream`

```
public static boolean isPrime(final int number) {
   return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number / 2).anyMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Проверка от обратного (true - это число не целое, false - число целое):

```
if (n % 2 != 1 && n % 2 != 0) {
     ...
}
```