# Помогите вывести простые числа в java

Tags: java

Помогите составить программу в JAVA которая принимает целое число, выводит на экран все простые числа от нуля до принятого числа. Используя только простые операции if и for 
Я составил, но что-то не помогает
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class prostue_chisla {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите положительное число: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        boolean b = true;
        for (int P = 1; P <= input; P++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < P; i++)
            {
                if (P % i == 0){
                    b = false;
                }
            System.out.println(P);}
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам переменная `b`? Что конкретно в приведённом коде работает неправильно?

Comment: Вот что оно выдает:Введите положительное число: 
5
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
5

Answer (score 2):

Если используете `java 8+`, лучше юзать в вашем случае `IntStream` для целых чисел:

```
public static boolean isPrime(final int number) {
   return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, number / 2).anyMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
}
```

Использование:

```
System.out.println(isPrime(1)); // false
System.out.println(isPrime(2)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int top = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i=2;i<top;i++){
        if(checkSimple(i))
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static boolean checkSimple(int i){
    if (i<=1)
        return false;
    else if (i <=3)
        return true;
    else if (i%2==0 || i %3 ==0)
        return false;
    int n = 5;
    while (n*n <=i){
        if (i % n ==0 || i % (n+2) == 0)
            return false;
        n=n+6;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Алгоритм проверки на то, что число является простым взял отсюда : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Что-то все равно не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не со сканером, а с алгоритмом. Во-первых, он не оптимален, во-вторых, содержит ошибку. Но, если вы хотите искать простые числа именно таким способом, исправьте свой метод таким образом

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите положительное число: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = in.nextInt();
    boolean b = true;
    for (int P = 2; P <= input; P++) {
        for (int i = 2; i < P; i++) {
            if (P % i == 0) {
                b = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (b) System.out.println(P);
        else b = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот что выдает: Введите положительное число: 
5
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
5

Comment: может вы что-то неправильно скопировали, потому как у меня выдает 5 1 2 3 5

Comment: 1 - не простое...

Comment: Спасибо, но все скопировал правильно

Comment: меняем р=1 на р=2 и все хорошо, 1 не выводится

Comment: не знаю, правильно или нет, но у меня все работает и вывод именно такой, как я написал. импорт сканера должен быть такой import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: если ввести 10 должно вывести 2,3,5,7,

Comment: все именно так и есть

Comment: не могу вставить скриншот, я бы показал

Comment: а в чем проблема? может у вас стартует ваш класс с вашим методом? удалите свой класс, создайте новый класс и скопируйте туда этот метод. а потом запустите его

Comment: запустил через консоль сработало. В intellije idea выдает то что написал сначала

Comment: ну тут сложно угадать, что вы делаете не так... если у вас работает через консоль, то код правильный. надо разбираться с идеей

Comment: закройте проект , перезапустите идею, создайте новый проект, потом класс у и скопируйте метод. может просто сглючила ваша идея))

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: не за что, учите java))

Answer (score 0):

```
//variable 'input' is input numeric
for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
Integer rez = i;
for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
if (i % j == 0) {
rez = null;
break;
}
}
if (rez != null) {
System.out.println(rez);
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Программа проверяет, числа от 11 и до бесконечности, и выводит количество простых чисел на экран + все простые числа + время работы программы. При желании можно отключить массив и выводить только количество простых чисел, что ускорит время работы программы процентов на 30. Без проблем можно запилить еще один метод, для проверки и вывода чисел до 10 и при помощи if проверять n<=10 - - - выбирать корректный метод.

```
public class reshenie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 4;//начинаем с 4, т.к. до 10 нам известны все простые числа и программа их не обрабатывает.
        int n = 100000;//число до которого необходимо найти все простые числа
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();//создаем массив, необходим для вывода чисел на экран, можно и без массива, просто выводить каждое найденное простое число
        numbers.add(2);//добавляем в массив простые числа до 10(см count = 4)
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(7);
        Date startTime = new Date();//время старта
        for (int i = 11; i <= n; i+=2) {//проверяем все числа до нашего значения
            if (simple(i)) {//метод ниже
                count++;//меняем счетчик простых чисел
                numbers.add(i);//заносим простые в массив
            }
        }
        Date finishTime = new Date();//время окончания работы алгоритма
        long ct = finishTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();//время работы
        System.out.println("Время вычислений: " + ct + "ms");//вывод на экран времени работы
        System.out.println("Количество простых чисел: " + count);//вывод количества
        System.out.print(numbers);//вывод всех чисел

    }

    static boolean simple(int a) {//берем число i
        int p = 0;//переменная для определения результата
            if ((a % 2 == 0)||(a%10==5)) {//исключаем числа, которые заканчиваются на 5 и четные
            return false;
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(a); j += 2) {//делим на все нечетные числа до корня из i
                if (a % j == 0) {// если хотя бы на одно число делится, то остановка цикла, переход к следующему числу
                    p += 1; break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (p > 0) {//если p = 0, то возвращаем true, число простое
            return false;
        } else return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getArrayOfPrimeNumbers(int n) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;//флаг
        for (int j = 2; j <= Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i)); j++){//если число i не простое,
            //то хотябы один делитель будет находится в промежутке от 2 до sqrt(i)
            if ((i % j) == 0) { //Если j - делитель числа, устанавливаем флаг на false
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime){
            System.out.print(i + " ");//если делителей нет, то флаг не изменится
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 1; j < a; j++) {
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < j+1; i++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
                k++;
            }

        }
        if (k == 2) {
            System.out.println(j + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]